# Text area clear: Firefox not responding but chrome does

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was trying to clear text area after message sent. I tried following :

```
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $('#f1');

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function (data) {}
        });
        clearin();
        return false;

        function clearin() {
            $('#f1').each(function () {
                this.reset();
            });
        }
    }
});
```

But does not seem to work in firefox. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the form fields just use

```
$('#f1')[0].reset();//Clearthe input field in form
$("textarea").val("");//Clear the textarea field in form
```

Try this

```
$('#f1 input[type="text"],textarea').each(function(){
            $(this).val('');
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5926F/5/)

Comment: Isn't that essentially what his `clearin` function does, just in a more verbose way?

Comment: console says 
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the function definition outside the `$(document).keypress()` event.

```
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $form = $('#f1');

        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success : function(data) {
            }
        });
        clearin();
        return false;
    }
});
    function clearin(){
        $( '#f1' ).each(function(){
            this.reset();
        }); 
    }
```

Comment: Why does it have to be outside? It should work as long as it's in the scope of the function call.